# m3u8 segmenter not building in centos 6

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

when i try to make it show me error oplease find below error which i am getting

```
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
m3u8-segmenter.c: In function ‘add_output_stream’:
m3u8-segmenter.c:58: error: implicit declaration of function ‘avformat_new_stream’
m3u8-segmenter.c:58: error: nested extern declaration of ‘avformat_new_stream’
m3u8-segmenter.c:58: error: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
m3u8-segmenter.c: In function ‘main’:
m3u8-segmenter.c:343: error: implicit declaration of   function‘avformat_find_stream_info’
m3u8-segmenter.c:343: error: nested extern declaration of ‘avformat_find_stream_info’
m3u8-segmenter.c:390: error: implicit declaration of function ‘avcodec_open2’
m3u8-segmenter.c:390: error: nested extern declaration of ‘avcodec_open2’
m3u8-segmenter.c:397: error: ‘AVIO_FLAG_WRITE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
m3u8-segmenter.c:397: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
m3u8-segmenter.c:397: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[1]: *** [m3u8_segmenter-m3u8-segmenter.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/m3u8-segmenter'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Note: i have ffmpeg and all required libraries installed already

My ffmpeg vesrion below:

```
[root@localhost m3u8-segmenter]# ffmpeg -version
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 29 2012 17:53:48 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --shlibdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
FFmpeg 0.6.5
libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
```

Comment: "warnings being treated as errors" turn that off

Comment: It seems problem is in ffmpeg version.

Comment: i am using ffmpeg version 0.6

Comment: how do i turn off the warnings can you please help me with this

Comment: is this related to libav-compact.h file??? as i see that libav for older versions have been commented out in code??

Comment: Don't use the -Werror flag when compiling

Comment: I tried compiling by removing -Werror flag as mentioned by you, i am stil getting the same error please help